# iOS SDWebImage fade in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, fadein, sdwebimage

I'm been using SDWebImage(ver3.0) on my iOS app, and I want to fade in the new image of uitableviewcell once it loads like Path2.0, Pinterest, and Viddy.Thanks to [iOS SDWebImage fade in new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869390/ios-sdwebimage-fade-in-new-image), fade-in itself is working.
However, image in cell is loaded again when scrolling tableview.
This may be caused by a reuse of a cell.

Here is my code.

```
[cell.userImageView setImageWithURL:url
                   placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  cell.userImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                                  [UIView transitionWithView:cell.userImageView
                                                    duration:1.0
                                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                  animations:^{
                                                      [cell.userImageView setImage:image];
                                                      cell.userImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                                  } completion:NULL];
                              }
                          }];
```

Comment: Find out if SDWebImage does caching - if so, make sure you only animate non cached loads.

Comment: Thanks! Caching is done. But, I did not check I only animate non cached loads...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS SDWebImage fade in new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869390/ios-sdwebimage-fade-in-new-image)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Credit goes to @OzBoz for pointing out that the correct solution is to just confirm whether the image was retrieved from the network (not cached) and if so, perform the animation:

```
[cell.userImageView setImageWithURL:url
                   placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              if (image && cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone)
                              {
                                  cell.userImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                                  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                   animations:^{
                                                       cell.userImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                                   }];
                              }
                          }];
```

If you're concerned about the cell no longer being visible), you can also use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This method (not to be confused by the similarly named `UITableViewDataSource` method) will return non-`nil` if the row is still visible. This is very important to do in most `UITableViewCell` async image retrieval processes, but it turns out that `setImageWithURL` will cancel any prior image retrieval processes, so it's less critical to check this when using `SDImageWeb`.

Comment: Thanks!!Your code works well(I replaced the UITableViewCell type with my custom cell subclass)!! I didn't know I should check to see if a cell is still visible when asynchronous updating the cell. So, I learned a lot.

Comment: @Rob I'm just curious, I was using if (cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone) instead of                                  UITableView *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                  if (cell) for one time showing animation after loading data from http. After I use your if statement, I could not figure out why cell comes as zero if the image in cell cashed before.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the answer. But, still something is not clear. Logic behind of using 'cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone' to check if the data comes from web then make animation. If not, then do not because cached image should immediately shown without animation (like instagram app). The thing I could not understand is why cell become nil (Reused by another row) if the setting image to imageview is pre-loaded. If I change the link of image in the second row, cell become non-zero. Why is this like that?

Comment: @Rob Moreover,`[cell.userImageView setImage:image];` is also redundant. Because after image downloaded, SDWebImage handled setting the image already itself.

Comment: @OzBoz You are quite right that if you want to check to see if you're asynchronously retrieving image from the web (and thus need animation) that you should just check `if (cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone) ...`. I've updated my answer accordingly. My prior answer about `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only critical if you're asynchronously retrieving an image and the cell has subsequently scrolled off before the async image retrieval is done. But it turns out that `SDWebImage`, when called on a reused cell, will cancel previously queued network operations, so this is of negligible concern.

Comment: It makes UITable view scrolling jerky also when I push to table view  from another view controller, slight lagging was there. How can I resolve this ?